# Passing Objects as Arguments to Dispatcher.Invoke in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, invoke, dispatcher

I have created a **BitmapImage** Variable in a new thread and need to pass as **Argument** of **Dispatcher.BeginInvoke** to **UI Thread**.

But Error Occurred:

**Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation**

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll**

This is my Code:

```
Public Delegate Sub NewDeleSub(ByVal InputImage As BitmapImage)
Private MyThread As Thread


Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded

    MyThread = New Thread(AddressOf NewThread)
    MyThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
    MyThread.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub NewThread()

    Dim InImage As New BitmapImage(New Uri("Image Path"))
    Me.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(New NewDeleSub(AddressOf RotateImage), InImage)

End Sub

Private Sub RotateImage(ByVal Img As BitmapImage)

    Dim OurImg As New Image
    OurImg.Source = Img

End Sub
```

in these lines error occurred:

```
Private Sub RotateImage(ByVal Img As BitmapImage)

    Dim OurImg As New Image
    OurImg.Source = Img

End Sub
```

Comment: The Error is Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Comment: **String** & **Integers** can Pass as Argument to Dispatcher.Invoke but Object Variable Cant. How to send Objects?

Comment: Why do you think object can't be passed? don't derive that from your problem. I guess that you have more code in the `RotateImage` method? because with just those 2 lines of code, I don't think there is any exception here, the `OurImg` is just a new control and is not even set with any parent control.

Comment: The Problem is that after sending **BitmapImage** Object to sub **RotateImage**, Error Occurred.

Comment: What is the exact line at which the exception is thrown? what if trying commenting out that line (or even all the code inside `RotateImage`)?

Comment: exact error line: **OurImg.Source = Img**

Comment: I confused because If I send **String** or **Integers** instead of BitmapImage Object, It work

Comment: What is the actual error message?  Wrap the code that throws the exception in an exception handler and LOOK at the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly, i found answer. It just need to use `InImage.Freez` to be able to send between Threads.